# Glassfish still use default realm

Tags: web-services, security, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I have a secure web service (message authentification over ssl) bundeled in a war and I'm trying to use jdbcRealm to authentificate the user.
The jdbcRealm work fine with other ear apps but not for this .war
Actually glassfish is still using the fileRealm despite the configuration done in the web.xml

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure Area</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/xoxoServer/secondWS/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <!--<auth-constraint>
          <role-name>EMPLOYEE</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>-->
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>

    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>my_realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

In the console I get this :

```
FIN: [Web-Security] hasResource perm: (javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission /secondWS POST)
FIN: JMAC: UnsupportedCallback : javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
FIN: JMAC: In PasswordValidationCallback Processor
FIN: jmac login user [test] into realm: file using JAAS module: fileRealm
FIN: Login module initialized: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.FileLoginModule
FIN: JAAS authentication aborted.
INFO: SEC5046: Audit: Authentication refused for [test].
INFO: SEC1201: Login failed for user: test
```

How to fix this ?
Thanks.
ps:I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 b5 with jdk6

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by:

1. packaging the war into an ear
2. adding the realm in the glassfish-application.xml ( in the ear)